# Display errors OpenCart

Tags: php, function, error-handling, opencart

In PrestaShop I can display the errors with the function Tools::displayError() like this:

```
if (empty($email)) {
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Email is empty.');
        $this->doLog('ERROR: Email/username is empty');
    } elseif (!Validate::isEmail($email)) {
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Invalid email address.');
        $this->doLog('ERROR: Invalid Email address');
    }
```

Is there a similar way to do this in OpenCart? Is there a function i can use?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer http://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/opencart2/error-reporting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To Turn on error reporting, please follow :

- Go To **Admin Panel**
- Go to **System > Settings**
- Select your store from the list and click **Edit**
- Go to the **Server** tab
- To display errors, change **Display Errors** to **Yes**, If you want to log errors to a file, select **Yes** for **Log Errors**
- Enter in an **Error Log Filename**
- Click **Save**

### Print Custom error message inside *error.log*

```
$logger = new Log('error.log'); //just pass the file name as error.log
$logger->write('Custom Error Message');
```

You will see the error file inside **system-> storage-> logs-> error.log**

Comment: Thanks, but i want to use the code in our program. I work on a web export from our program to OpenCart. Do you how i can do this in my code?

Comment: Okay! So you want to display custom error inside error log file?

Comment: Yes. Is there a function i can use?

Comment: In prestashop i did it like this:                                                                     
          if (empty($email)) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Email is empty.');
            $this->doLog('ERROR: Email/username is empty');
        } elseif (!Validate::isEmail($email)) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Invalid email address.');
            $this->doLog('ERROR: Invalid Email address');
        }

Comment: You have to enable the error reporting first as mentioned above this will create a error log file. But as want to log custom messages inside log, I never did this with OpenCart. Let me try...

Comment: @StefWinter Could you please let me know your Open Cart version ?

Comment: I enabled the error reporting. I use Version 2.3.0.2

Comment: @StefWinter! Finally I am able to print custom error message using `$logger = new Log('error.log'); 
$logger->write('Custom Error Message');`. Please Check My updated answer

Comment: @StefWinter! Please check my updated answer and let me know if you are still not able to print the custom error message ?