# Opencart 1.5.6.4 using MariaDB

Tags: php, opencart, mariadb

I want to ask, is it possible to use Opencart 1.5.6.4 using MariaDB instead of MySQL? If it possible, what code/file that I need to change? Because when I use mariaDB, my OC not working anymore.

Comment: What is the error? Note: after you change the db, you have to reinstall OpenCart or migrate the database.

Comment: There's no error comes up. It's just my website not working (blank page). My server use mysql... my pc use mariadb... the web in my pc (localhost) is working properly.. but when I upload it to server. It came with blank page.

Comment: Just [activate the error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43344031/9618184). Also, you could look up in server error log.

Comment: I got "server gone away" error..

Comment: If you search by "[mariadb opencart server gone away](https://www.google.com/search?q=mariadb+opencart+server+gone+away)", you will get a lot of results. Try those solutions.

Comment: already tried so many ways from there... but no solution.

Comment: where is the server located (the one with maria db)?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it's located at SG Server

Comment: The most plausible explanation is the hosting having some problems. Try a different hosting.

Comment: But the hosting told me the problem is in the code. That's why I tried find solution. I have found about mariaDB is good with OC 2 or above. So I thought that maybe it cause trouble to OC 1.5.6.4. Do you use 1.5.6.4 with mariaDB? And no change you've done for that?